# Что выбрать для хранения файлов? (Картинки)

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование

возник вопрос насчет хранения файлов по типу картинок, Amazon Aws и Google Cloud просто не подходят, и точка. Желательно чтобы у сервиса так же был пробный период

Comment: ну тогда расскажите, какие у Вас требования к хранилищу и что именно останавливает от aws/google (ну кроме цены)

Comment: @KoVadim отталкивает меня aws потому что не может нормально подружится с моей карточкой, а google cloud вообще нормального api для людей не имеет

Comment: так это не проблема aws, это проблема банка

Comment: @KoVadim я знаю, но открывать новый банковский счет ради aws не очень хочется

Comment: возможно, нужно просто позвонить в банк менеджеру и попросить разблокировать международные платежи или что то подобное. У меня было с другим сервисом такая проблема, оказалось, для особых международных платежей у них есть специальные секюрные протоколы и банк с сервисом не мог договорится. Но по моей просьбе они на час выключили параною, я подключил сервис и снова назад все включили.

Comment: @KoVadim хм, интересно сейчас гляну

Comment: хороший банк заинтересован, что бы у Вас на счету были движения денег, что бы они приходили и тратились, и что ещё важно - что бы это были чистые (в плане закона) транзакции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можете попробовать Yandex Object Storage, это S3 совместимое хранилище от Яндекса, подобная услуга также есть у Mail.ru (Mail.ru Cloud Storage) и Сбера (SberCloud Объектное хранилище S3)

Comment: возможно, это хорошие сервисы, но они не везде доступны.

Comment: У меня возникают проблемы к подключением к Mail Ru Storage, скиньте пожалуйста как вы это делаете